# Keyboard shortcut to change Z-order in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have to model diagrams with a lot of components. What is really annoying is to change the Z-Ordner by using the context menu, so that all the components are visible and are not hidden by other ones.

I tried in vain to find a Keyboard-Shortcut to change the elements Z-Order. Is there any?

Or are there other more automatic means to find the correct Z-Order with the Enterprise Architect by just knowing which component is contained in another one?

Comment: There's an icon in the menu for it (IIRC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no keyboard shortcut for changing the z-order, but there are buttons that make it faster than using the context menu:
[image]

You could also fairly easily make a script to change the Z-Order of all elements in a diagram.

Elements shown on a diagram are know in the API as `DiagramObject` https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/16.1/add-ins___scripting/diagramobjects.html
The property `Sequence` controls the Z-order.

A script like this loops all diagramObjects in the current diagram, and sets the z-order.
The only thing you need is an algorithm to decide the optimal z-order.

```
sub main
    dim diagram as EA.Diagram
    set diagram = Repository.GetCurrentDiagram
    dim diagramObject as EA.DiagramObject
    for each diagramObject in diagram.DiagramObjects
        diagramObject.Sequence = <someValue>
        diagramObject.Update
    next
end sub

main
```

Comment: Since you can't call a script via a keyboard shortcut it's a bit pointless, isn't it?

Comment: @qwerty_so not really. You can call a script from a diagram, and fix **all** z-orders in one go. Much better than doing each one individually I guess, with or without keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Yes sure. If there IS some rule to find them. Often enough you have to choose manually where a shortcut would be the best choice. At least you now mention the toolbox icon :)